# Is there a wysiwyg web editor extension for VS2010?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, visual-studio-2010

I have been doing C#, HTML coding using VS2010 and MVC. VS2010 has been a very good product to help me with that.

Now I need to do some fairly simple static web pages.

Is there any VS2010 extension that can help me with that. From what I saw there's not much WYSIWYG built into VS2010.

How about Microsoft Expression Studio or other MS tools. Do any of those offer things that would help me out. All I need is a tool that will help me with placing my DIVs and my images in the right places.

Please don't remove or lock this question. It's a real question and I am NOT just asking for subjective opinions on which is better. I would like to know what Microsoft Products are out there and what people use.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you designing web layouts, even very basic ones, it is worth the time to learn html structures and CSS. Microsoft moved away from webforms, with absolute positioning (WYSIWYG), to MVC for very good reasons.

Answer (score 2):

There is Expression Web, I haven't used the wysiwyg side of it, but as a web IDE it is pretty good.

Also in VS2010, you can create an empty project and just add HTMl files to it, this  gives you the wysiwyg editor.